# How to compare user logged's field with other user in Django's views

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have following model:

```
import ephem

class Person(models.Model):
        username = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)
        slug = models.SlugField(blank=False)
        location = ForeignKey(Location, blank=True) # return longitude & latitude city from Pyephem library
        city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, default='')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.username

        def get_city(self):
           city = ephem.Observer()
           city.lon = float(self.location.longitude)
           city.lat = float(self.location.latitude)
           return city # return city from location field

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.pk:
                self.slug = slugify(self.username)
            super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How to make programmatically in django's views to compare ***between the attribute of logged user and attribute's other user***? which's the username field are based on slug & there's an additional object from other python library (Pyephem), something like following:

```
def detail(request, slug):
    instance = Person.objects.all()
    city = ........ # City from city fields at Person model, the city's value from current user logged have their value as city0 and city's values for other user have value as city1, city2, city3 Et seq...

    for distance in instance:            
        # if current user logged are visiting other user detail then compare them each other
        do something for city0 and city1, city0 and city2, city0 and city3 Et seq....
            distance = ... # calculate distance of city's user logged & city's other user
        # I'm not sure what to do in this area so it will get the results of comparing between attribute of current user logged and attribute of other user

        return render(
        request, "detail.html",
        {
            'distance': distance,
        }
    )
```

*UPDATED

I updated the model above based on @cezar answer and add the function for city:

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by **between each user**. All I can see is that you want to generate the value of a property based on two other properties. If that's what are you looking for, I'd override the `save` method and put the logic there.

Comment: @cezar thanks for reply, I changed my question...

Comment: `get_object_or_404` will return   a single object or raises `404` so why are you doing a forloop?

Comment: Also it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: What does the attribute `distance` of the model `Person` holds? Which distance it is? Distance to somewhere, distance from somewhere?

Comment: @cezar distance from between city's current user logged and  city's other user. The field of distance is not need to be save on database, or it can be ignore or delete it from model at all.

Comment: Wow. I get it that may be might not be great at explaining - but to get a good quality answer, take a minute to figure out what exactly you want. Looking at your edits, the question you started off with, vs the question you have now are miles apart. Take an example (for example values from database) and show what is the desired behavior so the community can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I understand, it is probable that many users got one slug in your model. So if you want to compare between logged user and group of users with some slug I would generate QuerySet and then iterate over.

```
def detail(request, slug=None):
    instances = Person.objects.filter(slug=slug)

    if instances.count() == 0:
        return HttpResponse('Slug returns 0 matches')
    else:
        for object in instances:
            do something for city0 and city1
```

---

Ok, thanks for more details! Now after post update I think `request.user` object is what you are looking for:

```
def calculate_distance(user1, user2):
    #do something here like:
    #user1.location.lat user2.location.long etc.
    return distance_between

def detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = Person.objects.get(slug=slug)
    observer_user = request.user

    #added below variable to clarify code
    user_to_be_observed = instance

    return calculate_distance(observer_user, user_to_be_observed)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am changed my question, please read it again. I am sorry for my language which's not too good to explain my need.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`user1 = Person.objects.get(pk=1)` 
Did you mean the `user` field of `Person` here ?
I think it should be `user1 = Person.objects.get(pk=1).user`

Moreover,
here

```
city1 = Person.objects.filter(city__name='value1')
```

, where `filter` method always return `QuerySet`, 
see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood from your question you want to calculate the distance between the cities of two different users - one is logged in and visiting the page (let's call him Visitor) and the other one's page has been visited (let's call him Host).

You have the model:

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth import User

class Person(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

# you can generate the slug automatically when a new Person
# is added for first time, it won't change the slug later
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.slug = slugify(self.username)
    super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now let's create generic views for `Person`.

`views.py`

```
from django.views import generic

from .models import Person

class PersonList(generic.ListView):
    model = Person

class PersonDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Person

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        This method add extra values like the distance
        between the Visitor's city and the Host's city.
        """
        context = super(PersonDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        visitor = self.request.user
        distance = # pseudocode: visitor.city - self.object.city
        context.update({'distance': distance})
        return context
```

In your template you have access to `distance` and can show it to the Visitor, so she can know how far her city is from the Host's city.
I don't have any experience with the library Pyephem, so you have to replace the line of pseudocode with a proper calculation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try your solution and accept it after succesfully. I will back soon

Comment: your answer is almost solve my problem but not for comparing between each user. Btw thank you for your participation.